# Debian Grub - display a splash image/animation for the entire course of the boot (similar to KUbuntu)?

Tags: debian, boot, grub, animation

**The issue -**
I am looking into displaying a splash image as soon as I start my computer instead of a blinking cursor. For instance KUbuntu does this, it displays an animation during the *whole boot* instead of blinking cursor/dmesg output.

**What I've tried -**
I tried installing plymouth and modifying grub configuration but I only get a blinking cursor for the first 10 seconds of the boot and then the default plymouth theme for a brief second, I want it to be displayed during the entire duration of the boot.

My */etc/default/grub* configuration:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: You may try vt.global_cursor_default=0 parameter, this hides the cursor...

Comment: @mcsquared Thanks for the suggestion. Although I wish to replicate the way KUbuntu adds a animation to the entire duration of boot.

Comment: I think it's before grub, perhaps in the kernel ?

Comment: @ctac_ I believe regular Ubuntu has also this, perhaps there is a way of modifying the Debian kernal to achieve what I described in OP or if not in a different way?